# Random Sampling vs Stratified Sampling

Tags: sampling, sampling-theory

I am reading the book: Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow by Aurélien Géron and am a little confused by the following segment:

> So far we have considered purely random sampling methods. This is
> generally fine if your dataset is large enough (especially relative to
> the number of attributes), but if it is not, you run the risk of
> introducing a significant sampling bias. ... For example,
> the US population is composed of 51.3% female and 48.7% male, so a
> well-conducted survey in the US would try to maintain this ratio in
> the sample: 513 female and 487 male. This is called stratified
> sampling: the population is divided into homogeneous subgroups called
> strata, and the right number of instances is sampled from each stratum
> to guarantee that the test set is representative of the overall
> population. If they used purely random sam‐ pling, there would be
> about 12% chance of sampling a skewed test set with either less than
> 49% female or more than 54% female.

I am not understanding two things here:

1. Why would purely random sampling have any chance of sampling a skewed test set?

If the US population is 51.3% Female and 48.7% Male, and they use purely random sampling, then each person has a uniform likelihood of being selected into the sample. Doesn't that mean that this should lead to a representative sample?

2. If there is indeed a chance of sampling a skewed test set, why is that 12%, and why does it hinge on having a test set with fewer than 49% females or more than 54% females? What is the relevance of 49% and 54%? They seem completely arbitrary.

I am aware this question has been posted here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294151/could-someone-explain-how-this-estimate-number-is-being-arrived-at

However, the answer only addresses how to get the 12% number (and in fact the answer is 12.5%, not 12%), and the points 1 and 2 that I have raised are not addressed.